# need at jobs identified by name (advanced atd daemon)

Tags: linux, cron, scheduling, at

Sometimes I'd like to delete or overwrite (or simply cat) an at job. Unfortunately, the at jobs are identified by a sequential number (file in /var/spool/cron/atjobs), which makes those operations complicated. Is there a way, probably an advanced atd daemon (or another general scheduler), which makes it possible to identify the jobs by name? I look for a general solution, for regular linux users.

Comment: "...for regular linux users." As opposed to what? *Special* linux users? :)

Comment: As opposed to the root user.